# Problem trying to call user function using ptrace - nanosleep causes crash

Tags: c, ptrace

I'm working on a project where I need to make a running program execute a function on demand. For this I am using ptrace. I know that this is possible because GDB does it.

Right now I am using an adapted version of the the code found on: https://github.com/eklitzke/ptrace-call-userspace
This program displays how to call fprintf in a target program.

The program I am facing appears when the called function uses nanosleep(). If nanosleep() is called while inside the function called by the tracer, the tracee crashes with a SIGSEGV, but only after the sleep is concluded. If the function is called normally by the tracee itself, everything works properly.

I concluded that the problem is related to how the function is called, probably something to do with the tracee's stack or it's register values. I already checked that the stack is 16 byte aligned when entering the function for example.

Code of the tracer is present in the github above (difference is the called function and I also removed the arguments)

Code for the tracee is simple a dummy process that prints it's PID every second.

Code for the function that is called:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void hello()
{
    struct timespec tim1;
    tim1.tv_sec = 1;
    tim1.tv_nsec = 0;
    struct timespec tim2;
    nanosleep(&tim1, &tim2);    
    puts("Hello World!!!");
}
```

When the traced program crashes the backtrace is as follows:

```
#0  0xfffffffffffffff7 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007effb0e6e6e0 in hello () at hello.c:10
#2  0x00007effb195c005 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007effb1435cc4 in __sleep (seconds=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c:137
#4  0x00000000004005de in main ()
```

The register values of the dumped core:

```
rax            0xfffffffffffffff7       -9
rbx            0x7ffc858a0e40   140722548903488
rcx            0x7effb1435e12   139636655742482
rdx            0x7ffc858a0df8   140722548903416
rsi            0x7ffc858a0df8   140722548903416
rdi            0x7ffc858a0e08   140722548903432
rbp            0x7ffc858a0e18   0x7ffc858a0e18
rsp            0x7ffc858a0df0   0x7ffc858a0df0
r8             0xffffffffffffffff       -1
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x7ffc858a0860   140722548901984
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x7ffc858a0ec0   140722548903616
r13            0x7ffc858a1100   140722548904192
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0xfffffffffffffff7       0xfffffffffffffff7
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

Output of the tracer:

```
./call_hello -p 17611
their %rip           0x7effb1435e10
allocated memory at  0x7effb195c000
executing jump to mmap region
successfully jumped to mmap area
their lib            0x7effb0e6e000
their func           0x7effb0e6e000
Adding rel32 to new_text[0]Adding func_delta to new_text[1-4]Adding TRAP to new_text[5]inserting code/data into the mmap area at 0x7effb195c000
setting the registers of the remote process
continuing execution
PTRACE_CONT unexpectedly got status Unknown signal 2943
```

If I remove the call to nanosleep everything works as expected - "Hello World!!!" is printed. As I said previously, the segmentation fault only occurs after the requested sleep of 1 second. I don't know how nanosleep is causing the instruction pointer to hold `0xfffffffffffffff7`.
Any suggestions or ideas on what I should look into in order to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

I am testing this on CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810.

Comment: How are you getting this function into the remote process? The code you linked relies on the function already being there. And how are you compiling your custom function? And have you considered an `LD_PRELOAD` library instead?

Comment: Do you need to run *arbitrary* functions in the tracee, or one or a small number of specific ones?  Do you need to be able to specify arguments? Because honestly, the whole idea seems a bit outlandish to me. There ought to be a better way or a viable alternative.

Comment: @DarkFalcon The function is in a linked shared library. This is only an example in order to demonstrate the problem. My goal is to make an arbitrary program which source isn't available to me (only the binary) call a function. I also can't modify the function that I want to call. I have considered LD_PRELOAD but that way I wouldn't be able to make the approach completely generic as it would rely on the target program using shared libraries. Compilation of the shared library is done as follows: gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic -ggdb hello.c
gcc -shared -ggdb -o libhello.so hello.o

Comment: @DarkFalcon The library will be injected in the future as done in https://github.com/kubo/injector.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Only a small number of specific ones. Yes, I need to specify arguments. If you have any idea for an alternative I welcome it! As I said in a previous comment I don't have access to the source of the program that needs to run the function. The function contains code that although I have access to, I can't modify.

Comment: The address of the function in the top stack frame in your trace is suspicious.  It seems likely that the SEGFAULT arises from trying call a function at that address.  Can you reproduce the error with GDB as your tracer?  If so, then likely you're running into a limitation of `ptrace` and / or your environment.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, if I attach to the dummy process using GDB and call the function hello(), it works correctly.

Comment: What is the output of the tracer? (Please add the output in your question with the "edit" function)

Comment: @Ctx I edited the question. I also replaced the backtrace and register contents so that the address values came from the same execution.

Comment: That you do not reproduce the problem when using `gdb` as tracer suggests that the problem is in the tracer, not tracee, but you have not presented the tracer code you're using.  (Reference to a git repo is not "presenting", especially when the code you're actually using must be a modified version.)  You can best help us to help you by presenting a [mcve].

Comment: Is the sleep time of `1` second relevant? What about 2 seconds? 0.001 seconds? Can you check other syscalls? `sleep`? hm... `sched_yield()`? `clock_nanosleep()`? `alarm()` ? Maybe open stdin and call `select` with a timeout? What glibc version do you have? Really, `nanosleep` it's just a syscall.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I didn't post the tracer code because I am having trouble showing in a minimal way the introduced changes. The tracer is relatively large and I don't really know how to present it in a mininal way. Is is acceptable to post the code I am using on a git repository and sharing it that way? Or showing the `diff` between both versions?

Comment: @DanielGranhão, no, our expectation here is that questions will be complete and self-contained.  Moreover, no, we don't want to see the *changes*, we want a minimal, but complete, example code with which we can reproduce the problem.  Follow the link in my previous comments for details about that, and consult [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @KamilCuk No, the sleep time doesn't matter. Using `sleep` yields the same result, it probably internally calls `nanosleep`. Using `sched_yield()` works fine. `clock_nanosleep()` doesn't cause a SEGFAULT but doesn't sleep for the specified time, I think it must receive the signal relative to the sleep already present in the tracee and resumes earlier than expected. I think this might be helpful. GLIBC  2.17.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, I will try and improve my question taking into account your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is as follows:

Your call-hello program writes the two instructions

```
syscall
call %rax
```

to the memory where the current value of the %rip register (instruction pointer) points to. Since your target program has an (implicit) call to `nanosleep()` in its main loop, the %rip points almost always to the return address of the syscall (somewhere in the libc). At this point, the syscall executes `mmap()` and then jumps to the return value (the freshly mmapped space).

But later, in your `hello()` function, you *again* call `nanosleep()`. At the return address, there *still* is the injected code above! Some random syscall is executed (depending on the content of %rax), which fails with error code -9 (EBADFD), which is `0xfffffffffffffff7` in %rax now. Then, the `call %rax` jumps right there, killing your process.

So, the best solution is to find a place, where you can inject and execute the 4 bytes of code without overwriting other code. Alternatively, you can *restore* the original code before continuing to execute `hello()` and put it in again after execution of `hello()` ended (after the trap), as for example like this:

```
// update the mmap area
printf("inserting code/data into the mmap area at %p\n", mmap_memory);
if (poke_text(pid, mmap_memory, new_text, NULL, sizeof(new_text))) {
  goto fail;
}

- if (poke_text(pid, rip, new_word, NULL, sizeof(new_word))) {
+ if (poke_text(pid, rip, old_word, NULL, sizeof(old_word))) {
  goto fail;
}
```

Later, however, you have to reinstall the syscall-code briefly to make the `munmap()` call happen, for example here:

```
if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &newregs)) {
  perror("PTRACE_SETREGS");
  goto fail;
}

+ if (poke_text(pid, rip, new_word, NULL, sizeof(new_word))) {
+   goto fail;
+ }

new_word[0] = 0xff; // JMP %rax
new_word[1] = 0xe0; // JMP %rax
```

Now it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the really well explained answer!!